# Yii framework, CSS not found (404)

Tags: css, iis, yii, less

So I've got Yii setup on a linux box as my dev environment.  Everything looks good and works great.  Then I deploy it to a production machine using IIS.  Since I don't have access to IIS Manager, I'm pretty limited in what I can do configuration-wise.

On the production machine, everything works, including logging in and interacting with the database, but the css doesn't load, and after opening firebug, this is apparently caused by a 404 not found.

Other css files, even in the same folder, load just fine.  Is it somehow an issue with IIS server blocking download of .less files?  If so is there a way around it?

My site is at `http://mysite/index.php/mycontroller/myaction`
and the firebug console says the css it's looking for is at `http://mysite/css/main.less`

Code in layout file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.less" />

$baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/less-1.3.0.min.js');
```

Comment: you can not reference less files in you html. you have to compile less to css and then reference that css file in you page.

Comment: well I've included the javascript file that's supposed to handle doing that, which is what is firing in Firebug's console.  Updated to include the code I use to include the files.

Comment: It's possibly related to the MIME type settings on IIS. Having absolutely no experience with IIS I am just taking a stab-in-the-dark.

Comment: Silly question, but does main.less actually exist on the server's filesystem at the webroot/css/main.less?

Comment: Yes it does, that was something I did check to make sure, and would be a good reason for it not to work.

Comment: Can we see the corresponding rendered HTML (i.e. a view source, as opposed to the firebug HTML)?

Comment: Let me get that after work tonight, and we can take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

> <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="<?php echo
>   Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/css/main.less" />

and make right mime type or rename  `main.less`  to   `main.css`

Comment: Eventually I got a mime type added by the server guys.  Unfortunately when I had to restore my files after a git merge bricked it, it stopped working.  Used your solution of renaming to .css, worked like a charm.